# How to format to json with difference between comma of data/key and comma from text?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to improve this code so that it can handle a specific case.

Currently it works, unless the user adds a text with a comma

Here is my input who work (look only "note" key/value)

```
Input_OK =  2020-11-25,note:my text,2020-11-25,today:2020-11-25,2020-09-14,start:2020-09-14
```

In this case : `my text` is ok because there is no comma

```
Input_NOK =  2020-11-25,note:my text, doesn't work,2020-11-25,today:2020-11-25,2020-09-14,start:2020-09-14
```

In this case : `my text, doesn't work` is not ok because there is comma

With this specific input `2020-11-25,note:my text, work now,2020-11-25,today:2020-11-25,2020-09-14,start:2020-09-14`
I try to have this output

```
[{"release_date":"2020-11-25","today":"2020-11-25","note0":"my text, work now"},{"release_date":"2020-09-14","start":"2020-09-14"}]
```

Here is my current code

```
// before this input I add string to a list<String> for each date like that [2020-11-25,note0:test, 2020-11-24,my text, with comma, 2020-11-15,today:2020-11-15, 2020-09-14,start:2020-09-14] 

//After I remove space and [ ]

// myinput 2020-11-25,today:2020-11-25,2020-11-25,note0:my text, with comma,2020-09-14,start:2020-09-14

      var inputItarable = myinput.toString().split(',').where((s) => s.isNotEmpty);
      print("inputItarable   ${inputItarable} ");
//inputItarable   [2020-11-25, today:2020-11-25, 2020-11-25, note0:my text, with comma, 2020-09-14, start:2020-09-14] 

      
      var i = inputItarable.iterator;
      
      var tmp = {};

      while (i.moveNext()) {
        var key = i.current; i.moveNext();

        var value = i.current.split(':');
        (tmp[key] ??= []).add(value);

      }


      var output1 = tmp.keys.map((key) {
        var map = {}; map['release_date'] = key;
        tmp[key].forEach((e) => map[e[0]] = e[1]);
        return map;
      }).toList();

      var output2=json.encode(output1);
      print("output2   $output2 ");
  // output2   [{"release_date":"2020-11-25","today":"2020-11-25","note0":"my text, with comma"},{"release_date":"2020-09-14","start":"2020-09-14"}]
```

[Edit] I have a spécific case, where user back ligne, and have an input like that

```
myinput 2020-11-25,today:2020-11-25,2020-11-25,note0:my text, 
with comma,2020-09-14,start:2020-09-14
```

in this example I don't know how to replace the back ligne between `my text,` and `with comma` by `my text,\nwith comma`

Comment: can it be assumed that user text always start with 'note:' and ends with ',2020-'. So we can sanitize to remove all comma between these two, so that the string can be processed?

Comment: it's the inverse but still same, it's start with date 2020-  and after note: but I don't understand what you want to do

Comment: as long as I have output structured like that : [{"release_date":"2020-11-25","today":"2020-11-25","note0":"my text, with comma"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the code below or you may directly run it on Dartpad at https://dartpad.dev/1404509cc0b427b1f31705448b5edba3

I have written a sanitize function. What the sanitize function does is it sanitizes the text between the **possibleStart** and **possibleEnd**. Meaning it replaces all the commas in user input text with §. To do this it assumes that the user input starts with **,note:** or **,note0:** and ends with **,2020-** or **,2021-**. This sanitized string is passed to your code and in the end § is replaced with ",". Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import 'dart:convert';

String sanitize(
    String input, List<String> possibleStart, List<String> possibleEnd) {
  final String start = possibleStart.join("|");
  final String end = possibleEnd.join("|");

  final RegExp exp = RegExp("(?<=$start)(.*?)(?=$end)");
  final Iterable<Match> matches = exp.allMatches(input);
  matches.forEach((match) {
    input =
        input.replaceFirst(match.group(0), match.group(0).replaceAll(",", "§"));
    return true;
  });
  return input;
}

void main() {
  String myinput =
      "2020-11-25,today:2020-11-25,2020-11-25,note0:my text, with comma,2020-09-14,start:2020-09-14";

  myinput = sanitize(myinput, [",note:", "note\\d:"], [",20\\d\\d-"]);

  var inputItarable = myinput.toString().split(',').where((s) => s.isNotEmpty);
  print("inputItarable   ${inputItarable} ");
//inputItarable   [2020-11-25, today:2020-11-25, 2020-11-25, note0:my text, with comma, 2020-09-14, start:2020-09-14]

  var i = inputItarable.iterator;

  var tmp = {};

  while (i.moveNext()) {
    var key = i.current;
    i.moveNext();

    var value = i.current.split(':');
    (tmp[key] ??= []).add(value);
  }

  var output1 = tmp.keys.map((key) {
    var map = {};
    map['release_date'] = key;
    tmp[key].forEach((e) => map[e[0]] = e[1]);
    return map;
  }).toList();

  var output2 = json.encode(output1).replaceAll("§", ",");
  print("output2   $output2 ");
}
```

Comment: Cool Please accept the answer if it solves your issue. Thanks.

Comment: I faced some exceptions, It doesn't work if user press "enter" (back to next lign) sorry I don't know how tell this in english ^^ I have this error "The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length"

Comment: sorry :) for exemple if user back to ligne ( \n )  input= "my text, \n with jump and comma" I have error

Comment: But I have given you the code you need to be able to make minor adjustments to it, please see here I have fixed the code for you - https://dartpad.dev/1404509cc0b427b1f31705448b5edba3 all it need was to replace \n with some other character user is unlikely to input and then replace it back to \n in the end. So I fixed the 2nd line under main() like this myinput = sanitize(myinput.replaceAll("\n", "¦"), [",note:", "note\\d:"], [",20\\d\\d-"]); and then the second last line like this var output2 = json.encode(output1).replaceAll("§", ",").replaceAll("¦", "\n");

Comment: Thank you, it's work with \n, but ... I don't understand I verify and my input doesn't show \n but only a back ligne so it's doesn't work. I don't found how to detect or replace back ligne with \n

Comment: Please check now, the updated code is available on this URL - https://dartpad.dev/1404509cc0b427b1f31705448b5edba3